# How to navigate to activity on navigation drawer item click

Tags: java, android, androidx, android-jetpack

This is my main activity i want to navigate to an activity on my navigation drawer item click. I have checked the old way of achieving this i.e using switch statement and using onNavigationItemSelected method.
I know this is a question frequently asked, but after reading the many questions and solutions on stack overflow I am confused. I am confused with regards to Fragments and what is required to start an activity from clicking an item in the navigation drawer.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import android.view.View;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

**mobile_navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.vdosol.navigationdrawer.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:name="com.vdosol.navigationdrawer.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_gallery"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_gallery" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:name="com.vdosol.navigationdrawer.ui.slideshow.SlideshowFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_slideshow"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_slideshow" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_tools"
        android:name="com.vdosol.navigationdrawer.ui.tools.ToolsFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_tools"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_tools" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_share"
        android:name="com.vdosol.navigationdrawer.ui.share.ShareFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_share"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_share" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_send"
        android:name="com.vdosol.navigationdrawer.ui.send.SendFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_send"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_send" />
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do the following to navigate:

```
MenuItem logOutItem = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_logout);
        logOutItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
//do your stuff
                return true;
            }
        });
```

your AppBarConfiguration and Nav Controller should not contain above id ie "nav_logout" (in my case):

```
mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_plan, R.id.navigation_history, R.id.navigation_about, R.id.navigation_feedback, R.id.navigation_notifications)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
```

your menu should only contain in your menu file....no need to add it to you AppBarConfiguration and your NavController....

hope this helps....happy coding

Answer (score 2):

1. Implement the listener in your Activity:

   ```
   public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
                 NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
   ```
2. setNavigationItemSelectedListener in onCreate of Activity

   ```
   NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.account_navigation_view);

   if (mNavigationView != null) {
           mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
   }
   ```
3. Override the method

   ```
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
       int id = item.getItemId();

       if (id == R.id.nav_account) {//DO your stuff }
       ...
   }
   ```