# Navigation Drawer item click

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have *DrawerLayout* and *NavigationView*. There are two fragments which are changed when I click on item in navigation drawer and that works well:

```
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:label="@string/menu_settings"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" />

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_themes"
            android:label="@string/menu_themes"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_themes" />
```

The problem is that I have several other items in the drawer menu that are not Fragments and I can not make them clickable:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group
            android:id="@+id/group_1"
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_keyboard_settings"
                android:title="@string/menu_settings" />
        <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_themes"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_theme"
                android:title="@string/menu_themes" />
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group_2">
        <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_developer_page"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_developer_page"
                android:title="@string/menu_developer_page" />
        <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_privacy_policy"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_privacy_policy"
                android:title="@string/menu_privacy_policy" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Here is the code:

```
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        toggle = object : ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer_layout, toolbar, 0, 0) {
            override fun onDrawerClosed(drawerView: View) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView)
                syncState()
            }

            override fun onDrawerOpened(drawerView: View) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView)
                syncState()
            }
        }
        toggle.syncState()
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.nav_settings, R.id.nav_themes, R.id.nav_developer_page), drawer_layout)
        nav_view.setupWithNavController(navController)
        toggle.syncState()
```

When I set *NavigationItemSelectedListener* it breaks navigation for Fragments.

How can I make those two items clickable and call a function?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to get the menu item from the navigation view and set a click listener:

```
    val signoutMenuItem = binding.nvNavigationDrawerNavigationView.menu.findItem(id.navigation_drawer_menu_sign_out)
    signoutMenuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
        navigationDrawerMainActivityViewModel.signOut()
        true
    }
```

and do not include non-fragment items in `AppBarConfiguration`:

```
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            id.drawerFragmentX,
            id.drawerFragmentY,
            //id.navigation_drawer_menu_sign_out <- Do NOT include
        ), drawerLayout
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

This solution is identical to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59451345/5189200.

Xavi